# What is the probability that their first two goals are both 1 point goals?

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Consider a sports team who scores 1 point goals as a Poisson process of rate $\alpha$ and 3 point goals as an independent Poisson process of rate $\beta$. What is the probability that their their first two goals are both 1 point goals? 
What is the probability that the team scores two 1 point goals before they score two 3 point goals?

Anyone can help me to explain the structure of the question? This topic is new for me.

Answer (score 0):

This question relies on the relationship between the Poisson and Exponential distributions (see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/relationship-between-poisson-and-exponential-distribution)). Here's one way to approach the first problem:

1. In order for the first two goals to be 1-point goals, at least two 1-point goals must occur before the first 3-point goal.
2. If you knew the time of the first 3-point goal, could you calculate the probability of two or more 1-point goals occuring before that?
3. How can you move from the probability of two 1-point goals occurring before the first 3-point goal, conditional on the time of the first 3-point goal, to the full probability of interest? (Hint: try to integrate using the probability density function for the time of the first 3-point goal).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand your view. Can you explain your third point.

Comment: I was thinking you could use the [law of total probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035418/can-we-prove-the-law-of-total-probability-for-continuous-distributions) there. You have the probability of the first two goals being 1-point, conditional on the time at which the first 3-point goal occurs. You know the probability density function for the time at which the first 3-point goal occurs (it's exponential). Combine the two, and you should get what you're looking for.