# Are $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \xi_i / i$ and $\max\xi_n$ equally distributed?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let the random variables $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots, \xi_n$ be independent, have an exponential distribution and expectation of each is 2.

Are $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \xi_i / i$ and $\max\xi_n$ equally distributed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The argument in [this blog post](https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/expectedmaxexponential/) shows that they are equal in mean, but it can be extended to show they are actually equal in distribution.

Let $a(1),\dots,a(n)$ be the (random) ordering of the indices such that $\xi_{a(1)}\leq \xi_{a(2)}\leq \cdots \leq \xi_{a(n)}$. Then
$$\max(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)=\xi_{a(n)}=\xi_{a(1)}+(\xi_{a(2)}-\xi_{a(1)})+\cdots+(\xi_{a(n)}-\xi_{a(n-1)}).$$
Since $\xi_{a(1)}$ is the minimum of $n$ independent $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ random variables, its distribution is $\text{Exp}(n\lambda)$.

Since $\xi_{a(1)}$ is the smallest of the $\xi_i$, we have that $\xi_{a(2)}-\xi_{a(1)}$ is the minimum of $n-1$ independent $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ random variables, namely
$$\xi_{a(2)}-\xi_{a(1)}=\min_{i \neq a(1)}(\xi_{i}-\xi_{a(1)}).$$
Note that $(\xi_i-\xi_{a(1)})\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ for $i \neq a(1)$ by the memoryless property of the exponential distribution. Thus $\xi_{a(2)}-\xi_{a(1)}$ has the distribution $\text{Exp}((n-1)\lambda)$, and it is independent of $\xi_{a(1)}$ by the memoryless property.

Next we have $\xi_{a(3)}-\xi_{a(2)}$ is the minimum of $n-2$ independent $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ random variables:
$$\xi_{a(3)}-\xi_{a(2)}=\min_{i \neq a(1),a(2)}(\xi_{i}-\xi_{a(2)})$$
and so has the distribution of $\text{Exp}((n-2)\lambda)$. It is independent of $\xi_{a(1)}$ and $\xi_{a(2)}-\xi_{a(1)}$ by the memoryless property.

Continuing this argument, we have that $\max(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$ is the sum of $n$ independent exponential random variables with rates $n\lambda,(n-1)\lambda,\dots,\lambda$.

On the other hand, $\frac{\xi_i}{i}$ is an exponential random variable with rate $\lambda i$. Since the $\xi_i$ are independent, $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\xi_i}{i}$ is the sum of $n$ independent exponential random variables with rates $\lambda, 2\lambda, \dots, n\lambda$. So we conclude that $\max(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\xi_i}{i}$ are equal in distribution.

Comment: What is the sense of statement: $(\xi_i-\xi_{a(1)})\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ for $i \neq a(1)$ ? As $a(1)$ is random, what do you mean? Maybe you meant smth.like conditional distribution in case $i \neq a(1)$, but in this case it's not a memoryless property and should be proved.

Comment: Conditional on $a(1)=j$ (i.e., conditional on $\xi_j = \min(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$), $(\xi_i-\xi_j) \sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ for $i \neq j$, and these are independent of each other and of $\xi_j$.

Comment: It's not a memoryless property. Put $j=2$, $n=3$, $\xi = \xi_1$, $\eta =\xi_2$, $\zeta = \xi_3$. You say that $P(\xi_1 \ge \eta+x, \zeta \ge \eta +y|\min(\xi, \zeta) \ge \eta) = P(\xi \ge x) P(\zeta \ge y)$. Why do you say that it is a memoryless property? Maybe you want to derive it from smth.like $$P(\xi_1 \ge a+x, \zeta \ge a +y|\min(\xi, \zeta) \ge a) = P(\xi \ge x) P(\zeta \ge y) (1),$$ but it was not derived. Moreover, it's still not a memoryless property by definition. Because there are 2 r.v.in it, but not 1. So (1) also should be derived. Or what do you imply by "memoryless property"?

Comment: $\xi$ and $\zeta$ are conditionally independent given $\min(\xi,\zeta) \geq \eta$. So we can break up the joint conditional probability $P(\xi \geq \eta+x,\zeta \geq \eta+y\mid \min(\xi,\zeta) \geq \eta)$ as the product of $P(\xi \geq \eta+x\mid  \min(\xi,\zeta) \geq \eta)$ and $P(\zeta \geq \eta+y \mid \min(\xi,\zeta) \geq \eta)$. 

The first of these simplifies to $P(\xi \geq \eta+x\mid \xi \geq \eta) = \int_0^\infty P(\xi \geq a+x \mid \xi \geq a) f_\eta(a) \ da = \int_0^\infty P(\xi \geq x) f_\eta(a) \ da = P(\xi \geq x)$. Similarly with the second term.

Comment: Conditional independence of $\xi$ and $\zeta$ in case $\min(\xi, \zeta) \ge \eta$ means that $$P(\xi  > x, \zeta > y | \min(\xi, \zeta) \ge \eta) = P(\xi  > x| \min(\xi, \zeta) \ge \eta)  P(\zeta > y | \min(\xi, \zeta) \ge \eta) .$$  It's not hard to check if it's right but it's not a memoryless property. At least because there's only 1 r.v. in memoryless property.

Comment: Would you prefer I say it's an extension of the memoryless property or a consequence of it? As for the conditional independence, we can instead take the expectation over $\eta$ first:

$$P(\xi \geq \eta+x,\zeta \geq \eta+y \mid \min(\xi,\zeta) \geq \eta) = \int_0^\infty P(\xi \geq a+x,\zeta \geq a+y \mid \min(\xi,\zeta) \geq a) f_\eta(a) \ da.$$
Then split up the probability using conditional independence.

Comment: Let us call it extension. Put $\gamma = (\xi, \zeta)$. If I understood you right, you say  that $$P((\gamma, \eta) \in A | (\gamma, \eta) \in B) = \int_0^{\infty} P((\gamma, a) \in A | (\gamma, a) \in B) f_{\eta}(a)da {} (2) $$ (smth.like formula of total probability) and then derive the extension of memoryless property. If so, why does (2) hold true? It's not formula of total probability since it's not $$P((\gamma, \eta) \in A | (\gamma, \eta) \in B) = \int_0^{\infty} P((\gamma, a) \in A, \eta \in da | (\gamma, \eta) \in B) f_{\eta}(a)da. $$ If (2) is not true then the argument doesn't work.

Comment: See the derivation in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035418/can-we-prove-the-law-of-total-probability-for-continuous-distributions). You can adapt this to derive the formula (2).

Answer (score 1):

**Claim**: the statement is true and may be generalized easily for  any order statistic from exponential distribution with any $\lambda$, not only $\lambda = 2$.

At first, let us note that it's sufficient to consider $\lambda = 1$ since $\frac1{\lambda}$ is a scale parameter.

See proposition 3 p.55 here:<sup>1</sup>
https://doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177699058

So, the claim is true and may be showed by direct computation.

Moreover,
$$X_{(j)} = \sum_{i=1}^{j} \frac{\xi_i}{n-i+1}$$  in distribution.

<sup>1</sup>*Chernoff, H.; Gastwirth, Joseph L.; Johns, M. V. jun.*, [**Asymptotic distribution of linear combinations of functions of order statistics with applications to estimation**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177699058), Ann. Math. Stat. 38, 52-72 (1967). [ZBL0157.47701](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0157.47701).